# Pymysql reset cursor like mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have a piece of code which I migrate driver from mysql.connector to pymysql.
On mysql.connector there have cursor.reset(free=True), is there pymysql have functionality like that?

Comment: `close()` - This will just exhausts all remaining data.